# Google spreadsheets convert text date to spreadsheet date

Tags: google-sheets

I've imported a csv file in my spreadsheet which containing a date in this format

yyyymmdd
(20161018  for today )
To use this date in my new spreadsheet I use this formula

CELL T49 = 20161018

```
=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(left(T49;4);"/";mid(T49;5;2);"/";right(2)))
```

I was wondering if there is a more simple way to convert a text date to a spreadsheet date
It becomes relevant because you can not use concatenate in an "ArrayFormula"

Comment: How do you define "more simple way"?

Answer (score 2):

You could make your own function (cut/paste the script below into Tools>Script Editor) and then use `=DATEME(T49)`

```
function DATEME(input) {
  var input = input.toString();
  var year = input.substring(0,4);
  var month = input.substring(4,6);
  var day = input.substring(6);

  //JavaScript months are 0-11
  return new Date(year,month-1,day) ;
}
```

Comment: How is this custom function more simple than the formula provided by the OP? :)

Comment: I figure this one was harder for other users to mess up but I agree that it's not really 'simpler.' How about more robust?

Comment: I made a couple of small changes to your script: changed indices to get the month, and using new Date to return a date instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

`=DATEVALUE(TEXT(20161018;"0000-00-00"))`

next format cell as date.

---

`TEXT` function converts number format to string looking like date:

2016-10-18

`DATEVALUE` converts a provided date string in a known format to a date value

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and include of why this works?