# Converting funky datetime using Apps Script .toISOString() method

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a column of datetimes in the following funky format:

```
2016-07-07 12:34:47 -0700
```

I understand that I can convert this to a usable format by using the `.toISOString()` function in JS/Apps Script.

Not to be presumptuous, but can anybody easily manage this feat, help me take the first step, or even point me in the direction perhaps of a published Apps Script that can do this?

Thanks so much :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google spreadsheets convert text date to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115668/google-spreadsheets-convert-text-date-to-date)

Comment: thanks for the reply---that question is about how to convert yyyymmdd dates into a google sheets formatted date using a formula, while my question is about how to use apps script to convert _datetimes_ in the format above (not sure what it's called) into ISO8601 datetime format

Answer (score 1):

Return the Date object as a string, using locale conventions:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
```

Convert today's date into a readable string:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toDateString();
```

Other functions that might be useful:

```
.toUTCString()
.toString()
```